# Как показать стандартное окно, в котором отображется информация об определенном контакте?

Tags: java, android, activity, android-layout

В общем изучаю программирование на Android. У меня в приложении, когда нажимается кнопка, показывается список всех контактов:

[image]

Далее пользователь выбирает, какой-нибудь контакт. Контакт выбирается, все замечательно. После этого я хочу, чтобы показывалось стандартное окно информации о контакте. Например, так:

[image]

Но этого не происходит. Пытаюсь сделать это вот таким вот образом:

**MainActivity.java:**

```
// Показать список всех телефонных контактов и дать возможность пользователю выбрать один из них
public void viewContact() {
    // Start an activity for the user to pick a phone number from contacts
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
    intent.setType(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_TYPE);
    if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_VIEW_CONTACT_DETAILS);
    }
}

// Пользовать выбрал контакт. Теперь надо отобразить о нем информацию
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_VIEW_CONTACT_DETAILS && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Uri contactUri = data.getData();
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, contactUri);
        if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
            startActivity(intent);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Can't resolve activity", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml:**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"></action>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"></category>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

</application>
```

Получаю **Toast**

> "Can't resolve activity"

то есть `intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager())` равно `null` (система не может сопоставить ни одно активити для данного случая). Помогите пожалуйста.

Comment: я не уверен, что такое можно сделать. Не уверен, что у стандартного приложения "контакты" есть метод "покажи детали определенного контакта", который "выставлен наружу"

Comment: Ну а тогда, почему в документации приводится пример с ACTION_VIEW (который, кстате у меня, как я сказал раньше не работает) для того, чтоб смотреть детали о контакте? (смотрим главу про Common Intents)

Comment: Дайте ссылку на эту главу, я посмотрю

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common.html#Contacts

Comment: Листайте до View a contact

Comment: Какие значения параметров у вас приходят в onActivityResult?